# Remove Windows recovery partition on dev/sdb1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS l installed on my laptop and I woul like to remove windows 10 recovery option when starting my laptop.I just want to be redirected in my ubuntu without showing boot menu. Do you have any suggestion for me ?

[Boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT3n0.jpg)

Comment: do you really want to remove the partition or you just want to remove it from the grub menu?

Comment: I want to remove the partition cause I don’t need windows

Comment: Many of us feel the same way. ;)

Comment: Why 18.04 and not 22.04? Regarding recovery: if you plan to resell your machine it might be prudent to keep it. It is just a couple of Gbs :) "when starting my laptop.I just want to be redirected in my ubuntu without showing boot menu" If THAT is the problem see your grub config. You probably have it set to always show grub. Removing windows from grub menu does NOT make it NOT stop ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So you simple can delete that partition, like using `fdisk`. It is a dangerous operation, so be sure you delete the right partition!

If you don't want to waste the disk space, you can use `parted` after (or `gparted` for GUI) to resize your Linux partition and `resize2fs` to resize the filesystem on it (assuming you are using ext* filesystem)

After the partition removed the next grub update (eg when the next kernel update comes) will not detect any more the partition and will remove the item for the menu. But you can start the update manually too:

```
update-grub2
```